# Finder in Sierra: How to get "Up" to "Macintosh HD" or "Volumes"

Tags: finder, macos

Prior to 10.12, if I opened a Finder window and hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> a bunch of times, I'd get to `/Users`, then `Macintosh HD`, then `/Volumes`

Now in 10.12, I can get as far as `/Users` but then <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> becomes disabled.

I can still navigate directly to either location with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or by browsing via the sidebar. What's required to be able to navigate "up" to them from lower-level folders?

Comment: I'm on Sierra and it works for me... not sure what could be causing that. If you want, you can also set any directory to be the default in Finder preferences.

Comment: BTW, you can context-click on the Finder window title bar for a pop-up menu of each folder in the path.

Comment: Also, Command-Shift-C will take you straight to the "Computer" view, which I suspect is what you mean by /Volumes.

Comment: The context menu does still show "Macintosh HD" at the bottom of the list and clicking that takes me there, as does Command+Shift+C. It's just the "up" shortcut that's stubbornly broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but toggling `AppleShowAllFiles` on and then off again fixed this.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
killall Finder
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO
killall Finder
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous OS X by default used to show the hard drive icon on the desk top. Later versions including Sierra hide it by default. If you want to make it visible and accessible on the desk top and the finder window. Open up a new finder window by command N. go to finder preferences command,  (not to be confused with system preferences. Click or select the show 'hard disks' and the main drive will now show up.

Comment: Nope, sadly that doesn't seem to have any impact on the keyboard shortcut.